# Python least squares estimate error

Tags: python

I've got a data set that I'm trying to automate the analysis of. The data is a series of experiments and I need to get the slope of the plots.

Sample Data set:
[Sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzaV.png)

In addition to the data I have a flag that indicates the start of each of the curves that I'm trying to analyze conveniently (named CycleVec).

To find the slope I've used the following code:

CycleVev - list of system cycles, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.... etc

CycleValue - the cycle number I'm wantingto analyze

```
#+3 to cut off the first 3 data points to ignore occasional data error
startIndex = CycleVec.index(CycleValue)+3 

#-20 to cut off the last 20 data points to ignore recorded noise
endIndex = len(CycleVec) - 1 - CycleVec[::-1].index(CycleValue)-20 

ShortTime = TimeVec[startIndex:endIndex]
ShortForce = ForceVec[startIndex:endIndex]

A_Matrix = np.vstack([ShortTime,np.ones(len(ShortTime))]).T
mVal , cVal = np.linalg.lstsq(A_Matrix,ShortForce,rcond)[0]
```

This code seems to be working fine for getting an individual cycle slope. I've then tried wrapping this into a for loop like this:

```
maxCycles = int(max(CycleVec))

mVector = []
cVector = []

for CycleValue in range(1, maxCycles-1):
    #CycleValue = 22
    startIndex = CycleVec.index(CycleValue)+3
    endIndex = len(CycleVec) - 1 - CycleVec[::-1].index(CycleValue)-20

    ShortTime = TimeVec[startIndex:endIndex]
    ShortForce = ForceVec[startIndex:endIndex]

    A_Matrix = np.vstack([ShortTime,np.ones(len(ShortTime))]).T
    mVal , cVal = np.linalg.lstsq(A_Matrix,ShortForce,rcond)[0]
    mVector.append(mVal)
    cVector.append(cVal)
```

With this intending to create two lists (mVector and cVector) of the slope and offset. (offset i'm not using ever, just doing it for completeness)

When I run this i get a series of errors:

```
 mVal , cVal = np.linalg.lstsq(A_Matrix,ShortForce,rcond)[0]
 File "C:\Users\Morgan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1978, in lstsq
_assertNoEmpty2d(a, b)  # TODO: relax this constraint
 File "C:\Users\Morgan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 225, in _assertNoEmpty2d
raise LinAlgError("Arrays cannot be empty")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Arrays cannot be empty
```

Which I'm not really sure what to do with. I've populated the arrays in a similar way with no issue. Can anyone help? This is my first try at writing python, I'm a matlab veteran though.

Comment: Did you look at the values of `A_Matrix` and `ShortForce` before calling the function? Surely one of them (or both) is empty.

Comment: I thought for sure I had checked that, but I went through the data again. There's apparently a glitch in my data somewhere resulting in my start and end indices resulting in a negative range. I've added an if statement to confirm that endIndex-startIndex >0 which seems to have solved it. What is the 'correct' way to close out a question when the answer is sort of an oops in the data, not the code?